# PHP Complex Syntax - Generating Proper Values in Forms

Tags: php, forms

I have an application that prompts users to fill out a form. When they hit submit, they are redirected to another page to verify their information. If they select edit (as opposed to confirming its accuracy), they are redirected to the original forms.

In order to maintain the values across the pages, I am storing the initial form input in $_SESSION.

The second "verification" page:

```
$_SESSION['formInput'] = $_POST;
```

If the user goes back to the original form, I am then looping back through this data and placing the user's input in the appropriate fields.

```
if($_SESSION['formInput']) {
foreach($_SESSION['formInput'] as $key => $value) {

${$key} = $value;
```

Overall, this appears to work using something such as:

```
<label>First Name: </label><input type='text' data-validation='[NAME]' id='primaryOneFirst' value='{$primaryOneFirst}' name='primaryOneFirst' data-validation-label='Field' /></div><div class='formGroup colHalf'>
```

However, there is a portion of the form that is dynamically generated based upon how many children the visitor has (indicated on another page). Overall, my approach for this has worked far as accessing the data and sending it through email; however, I am having a lot of trouble getting the values retained.

For example, right know I have the following:

```
          $counter = 1;
          while($counter <= $numberOf) {

          $html .= "<div class='childField' id='child{$counter}'>

    <h3>Child Data {$counter}</h3>

    <div class='row'><div  class='formGroup colHalf'><label>Child Name: </label><input type='text' data-validation

='[OPTIONAL, NAME]' data-validation-label='Field' name='childName{$counter}'  value='{$childName}$counter' /></div>

<div class='formGroup colHalf'><label>Date of Birth:<select name='childBirthmonth{$counter}'>
                      <option value=''> </option>
                         <option value='01'>January
                         </option>
                         <option value='02'>February
                         </option>
                         <option value='03'>March
                         </option>
                         <option value='04'>April
                         </option>
                         <option value='05'>May
                         </option>
                         <option value='06'>June
                         </option>
                         <option value='07'>July
                         </option>
                         <option value='08'>August
                         </option>
                         <option value='09'>September
                         </option>
                         <option value='10'>October
                         </option>
                         <option value='11'>November
                         </option>
                         <option value='12'>December
                         </option>
                         </select>


                 <select name='childBirthday{$counter}'>"; for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
                         if($i < 10) {
                         $i = "0" . $i;
                         }   $html .=  "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
                         }   $html .=  "</select>
                         <select name='childBirthyear{$counter}'>";

                         for($i = 1900; $i <= date("Y"); $i++) {
                          $html .=  "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
                         }   $html .=  "</select></div>

                      </div>

                      <div class='row'><div class='formGroup colHalf'><label> SSN: </label><input type='text' placeholder='xxxxxxxxx' data-validation-message='Please enter a 9 digit SSN without dashes.' data-validation='[L==9, INTEGER, OPTIONAL]' value='$childSSN{$counter}' name='childSSN{$counter}' id='childSSN{$counter}' /></div><div class='formGroup colHalf'><label>Gender: </label><select value='childGender{$counter}' name='childGender{$counter}'><option value='male'>Male</option><option value='female'>Female</option></select></div></div>

                      <div class='row'><label>Please Check All That Apply:</label></div><ul class='checkBoxGroup' /><li>Handicapped: <input type='checkbox' name='handicap{$counter}' value='handicap' /></li><li>Full-Time Student: <input type='checkbox' name='student{$counter}' value='student' /></li><li>Step Child: <input type='checkbox' name='step{$counter}' value='stepChild' /></li><li>Foster Child: <input type='checkbox' name='foster{$counter}' value='foster' /></li><li>Different Address (than yours): <input type='checkbox' name='diff{$counter}' value='differentAddress' /></li></ul>

                      <div class='childAddressBox'><div class='row'><div  id='childAddress{$counter}'><div class='formGroup colHalf'><label>Address: </label><input type='text'  value='$childAddress{$counter}' name='childAddress{$counter}' /></div><div class='formGroup colHalf'><label>City: </label><input type='text' size=20  value='$childCity{$counter}' name='childCity{$counter}' /></div></div>

                       <div class='row'><div  class='formGroup colHalf'><label>State: </label><input type='text' size=2 value='$childState{$counter}' name='childState{$counter}'/></div><div class='formGroup colHalf'><label>Zip</label><input type='text' size=5 value='$childZip{$counter}' name='childZip{$counter}' /></div></div>
                       </div>
                       </div></div>";
                      $counter++;
      }
      echo $html;      
}
```

I have tried multiple approaches, but instead of getting the desired output (the child's name, SSN, or address), I am just getting the value of $counter (1). Instead of something like `value='{$childName}$counter'` or  `value='$childSSN{$counter}`' I need it to literally translate to somehing such as `value='{$childName1}'` or `value='{$childSSN1}` , just like the other portions of the form. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You can use `extract($_SESSION['formInput']);` instead of `foreach($_SESSION['formInput'] as $key ...`

Comment: When the customer submits the children's info, what does it look like in `$_POST`?  is it `$_POST['childName1']`,`$_POST['childName2']`,`$_POST['childSSN1]`,`$_POST['childSSN2']`... ?

Comment: That is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic fields like what is in your question, it is more appropriate to use arrays for managing the data. For this, you have to name the fields, using indexed syntax. For example, instead of this:

```
<input name='childName{$counter}'  />
```

You could write:

```
<input name='childName[$counter]'  />
```

So data will be parsed as arrays when they are sent to PHP.

Then, you probably can use such code to output desired values:

```
<input name='childName[$counter]' value='{$childName[$counter]}'/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your approach might be the proper one, but unfortunately at the moment, much of my code depends on the input being in the format I am already using. Again, I appreciate your answer, and I may end up having to go with it, but I am just seeing if there might be a quicker fix for my situation.

Comment: In that case, you may use some thing like this: `...name='childName{$counter}'  value='".$("childName" . $counter)."' /></div>...`

Comment: Or something like `value='{${childSSN . $counter}}'` inside your string

Comment: Thanks both. I tried Edu's solution, and it got me very close; however, I am receiving the following notice  `Undefined variable: childName1` ` However, I am perplexed as to why. A vardump on on my session variable, and even simply echoing out the variable reveals that it is defined: For example: `echo "Name is $childName1"` outputs the exact data it should (that is, the name I put in). In light of this, I am quite unsure why I am receiving the message. I would really appreciate any insight.